# When to use vh and min-height:100vh

Tags: html, css

I have unintentionally been learning HTML in quirks mode, now that I have put `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag in, it's throwing off what I've learnt so far. At this point I'm struggling to understand using percentages for heights and when to use VH...

Here is a fiddle, along with some questions: https://jsfiddle.net/kittenslayer123/q9dm1zmu/4/

My goal and thought process:

1.Have body wrap around multiple sections - so I set `body's min-height:100%`

2.Each section is to be 100% of window - so I set `.section height: 100vh`

3. Each section should initially be 100vh but expand to wrap around contents - in this case .section-child.
4. I want section to be 100vh and expand depending on content (section-child) - The way I set it, the 3rd section-child overflows onto the next section.

Can I set .section height to `100vh` without using vh?
Why is my .section not expanding? even though I have set `min-height:100vh`

I am really struggling to understand why or how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your section is not expanding because there is nothing in it. Once you fill it with content it will expand (granted that it exceeds 100vh)